# Trouble with elements outside TableVIew

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, ios7

I got a checkmark image, that snaps to TableView cell, and when this cell swipes — checkmark follows:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark.png"];
self.checkmark = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
self.checkmark.frame = CGRectMake(roller.originX - image.size.width, 0, image.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
self.checkmark.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRight;
self.checkmark.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.scrollableView addSubview:self.checkmark];
```

Sense iOS7 not so friendly to elements, placed outside TableView, I want to place it behind the cell at the beginning, and snap it only after cell passes this checkmark. But I can't figure out, how can I possibly do it.

Here's an example in step 1 and 2 how it works now, and how I'm trying it to do: https://www.monosnap.com/image/bQv8GlkmWG7UXnZgSitevZIsFuFz9z

I really will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the image as a background image for each of your cells, and make it's alpha zero and whenever user swipe and your swipe method gets called, change the alpha to 1.

Comment: But in this case, how should a checkmark snaps to the call, when it's dragged?